# Select jquery object by data attribute

Tags: jquery

My html fragment goes something like

```
<button data-file="day">Day</button>
<button data-file="night">Night</button>
```

and I'm trying to do the following in Jquery

```
var $button = $('button');
$button.data('file' , 'day').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

So make jQuery objects of all buttons then disable the button with data attribute day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the disabled state

```
var $button = $('button[data-file="day"]');
$button.prop('disabled' , true);
```

Update

```
var $button = $('button');
$button.filter('[data-file="day"]').prop('disabled' , true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned i have two buttons- Day and Night with matching data attributes data-file="day" and data-file="night. Can I make an object of both buttons i.e var $button = $('button') then select the day button via its data attribute?

Comment: Perfecto! Many thanks. Clearly I need to learn more methods. Many thanks.